# Apache UrlRouting Error

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting, url-routing

I use apache 2.4 on lmde2 (Linux-Mint-Debian2).

If i try to load a script located like this: "/var/www/html/site1/sites/weiteres.php"

Apache generate a link like this: "http://localhost/site1//var/www/html/site1/sites/weiteres.php". Maybe the error happens here: //

This would be right: "http://localhost/site1/sites/weiteres.php".

My apache2.conf at "/etc/apache2/apache2.conf" has this active:

```
    <Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
```

But the root directory is "/var/www/html/ it looks like there must be another configuration file.

Comment: Apache generate a link like this ?! Isn't it you typed the URL?

Comment: apache should generate url's out of lokal stuff like that "/var/www/html/site1/sites/weiteres.php", yes. 

I typed nothing.

Comment: No, Apache is a web server and doesn't "generate" anything. It serves files from directories, sometimes using a preprocessor (like PHP)

Comment: ok i explain it for you, sry for my bad english.

It's very simple. if you write a document in html or if you generate html with php it is the same. In html you make a link like this: <a src=/var/www/index.php> homepage </a> or in php something like this <php echo  "<a src='/var/www/index.php'> homepage </a>"; ?>

The Webserver-software (Apache) hast to generate out of a relative link like this "/var/www/index.php" a url like this: http://localhost/index.php 

Or if apache runs in www then www.big-tits.index.php.

This is the job from the apache webserver.